# Rails 3 Nested resource not in the same namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following on my routes file:

```
namespace :forum do
  resources :topics
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

So Topics and Posts Controllers are inside the Forum module (`Forum::TopicsController` and `Forum::PostsController`), but the Comments Controller is not (it's just `CommentsController`) because it's a polymorphic (so shared between some controllers).

The problem is that the application looks for `Forum::CommentsController` which obviously does not exist, how can I define no module for that resource?

I've tried, but didn't work:

```
namespace :forum do
  resources :topics
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, controller => 'comments'
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: actually rails will look for /forum/posts/:post_id/comments/ not for /forum/comments/

Comment: I mean from a controller perspective, so I get the error `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Forum::CommentsController)`

Comment: controller is polymorphic? didn't get this point.

Comment: you are right, the `Comments` model is the polymorphic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set the route for Comments manually

For example

```
match '/forums/:forum_id/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id' => 'comments#show'
```

So your Comments controller don't have to sit inside other modules

Comment: Thanks, I ended using this answer and it was the one with less impact on other stuff like route names.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess you want to re-use the codes in Comments controller. Is that right? If so, I do not know any direct answer to this question but I guess you may consider something like that.

## comments_controller.rb

```
module forum
  module posts
   class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     include Commentable
   end
  end
end
```

## commentable.rb

```
module Commentable 

end
```

Now you can use this commentable module anywhere you want to use. So, you are re-using common codes with two features:
1. you get freedom to change behavior per controller
2. you have to create separate files for each controller.

Comment: Interesting, it would need more rework so I ended using other answer, but this is definitely something to consider for improving my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the cleanest (and I'm not sure if there's a better way of achieving this), but you could use a scope rather than a namespace, and then explicitely set the controlller for resources in the Forum namespace:

```
scope '/forum' do
  resources :topics, controller => 'forum/topics'
  resources :posts, controller => 'forum/posts' do
    resources :comments
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your answer and it did work, but the route names dropped the forum on their names and I relied on those.